# Laravel: Get the values of the drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

View code looks like here:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="current">
            @include('cms.public.views.partials._messages')         
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead style="color:white">
                  <tr>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>ID<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>SLUG<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>ORDER<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>PUBLIC<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{$project->id}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And jquery code looks like here:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

How can I do it to get the values of the order when I drag and get the value of the order when I drop?

My idea is to update the DB when drag and drop, so I need to know which project change, and then substract or add 1 if go top or down.

Comment: use dropzone.js api wayy easy!

Comment: I remember used dropzone to files @Leo_Kelmendi I don't think it's too good idea to drag and drop rows of a table. Actually i used jqueryui, maybe can help me with that? I'm stocked, yesterday I post an other question but anything can help me

Comment: okay I thought u are dealing with file, check for any laravel package. jqueryUi seems an option but a lot of work to be done to achieve that

Comment: If no one answers I will check when I am on a pc for this

Comment: Yes, maybe have some library to make it a lot easier. I need make it really soon, i will really appreciate if when you can, help me:) Thanks @Leo_Kelmendi